# Laravel : Migration with Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, laravel

I know this question has been ask a lot of time but i tried every solutions and it still give me an error.

I want to migrate my tables :

```
class CreateFichesTable extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('fiches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->string('nom');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->integer('equipe_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('fiches', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->foreign('equipe_id')->references('id')->on('equipes');
    });
}
```

}

And

```
class CreateEquipesTable extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('equipes', function (Blueprint $table) {;
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nom');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

}

And I get :

```
Exception trace:

1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign 
key constraint")
```

I tried to force using the engine "InnoDB" but still not working.

Any tip ?

Comment: You must be firstly make `CreateEquipesTable` then `CreateFichesTable `

Comment: That what I thought but didn't find any info how to process this
I'm exectuting this command :
    php artisan migrate

Comment: In what order are these migrations executed?

Comment: If you see your migrations file they starts with date similar this `2018_08_10_111004_`, can you show that two files name??\

Comment: `2018_08_31_141536_create_fiches_table.php`
`2018_09_03_141649_create_equipes_table.php`
so i guess i have to change dates manually ?

Comment: change `2018_09_03_141649_create_equpes_table` to `2018_08_30_141649_create_equpes_table` and then `php artisan migrate`

Comment: It did the job, didn't know about that. thank you mate.

Comment: it is work correctly??

Comment: Yes eveything has been created successfully ! Ty again. I didnt paid attention the the creation table datetime,i thought laravel could handle easily handle this process by detecting foreign keys

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer so i can validate it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create new migration file laravel automatically added in the start datetime like this `2018_08_10_111004_` for detect which migration must be create firstly. As you show in comments your migration files is `2018_08_31_141536_create_fiches_table.php` and `2018_09_03_141649_create_equipes_table.php` you must be change one of this migration for firstly called second migration the first. 
For example

```
2018_08_31_141536_create_fiches_table.php 
2018_08_30_141649_create_equipes_table.php
```